# Code igniter multi select from database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, select

I'm trying to populate my multiselect from database but it selects only one value. In database I have column mselect with two values: "small, large".
Populating values from _POST shows only one value as well. What's wrong?

Bit from my model:

```
    function get_all() {
    return $this->db->get( 'settings' )->row_array(); //array
}
```

Bit from my view:

```
        $row = $this->lol_model->get_all();

        $m_name = 'multiselect';
        $m_options = array( 'small' => 'Small', 'medium' => 'Medium', 'large' => 'Large', 'xlarge' => 'ExtraLarge', );
        $m_selected = isset( $_POST[ 'multiselect' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'multiselect' ] : $row['mselect'];
        $m_extra = array( 'id' => 'multiselect', 'class' => 'w3-select', );
        echo form_multiselect( $m_name, $m_options, $m_selected, $m_extra ); //name, options, selected, extra
```

And in my controller I've setup validation, errors and loading views.

Edit:
I've found the way to use serialize function in php to store the data but is there different approach? CI set_select function will help?

```
        $m_selected = isset( $_POST[ 'multiselect' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'multiselect' ] : unserialize($row['mselect']);
```

In database I have column "settings" only with one row but do I still have to use foreach loop?

Comment: `->row_array()` only gets one row from the database. But even if you use `->result_array()` you need to loop trough the results. Show all relevant code if you don't know how to loop an array. Also you miss that using CI syntax for inputs is more secure (`$this->input->post('multiselect')` instead of `$_POST[]`

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I've found the way to use serialize and unserialize functions to read/write data but is there a way to do it differently? I will post my example in one sec.

Comment: One moment please.

Comment: There are big gaps in what you actually trying to achieve here: 1. `$m_selected` should ONLY have ONE value as it is used for selecting ONE of the options. 2. As I can read from your model you only get the first row from the settings table. So the contents of `$m_selected` will be the contents of the first DB row value in the field `mselect`. Are you saying that there are two values in the same DB field ("small, large")? That doesn't make sense as you would only want to select one of the values in the multiselect. Tell me what you expect to happen?

Comment: In CI Users guide they say that I can pass an array as the third parameter of the form_multiselect function and It does work when I'm working without database. Maybe set_select function will help? Why even set_select exist when I can use third parameter of form_multiselect  function?

I want to see in my multiselect which options are selected in the database (they are: small, large). Lets say user selects two options and they are inserted in one field in database. 

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_multiselect#form_multiselect

Comment: Ah, you got me, missed getting that! Then I would use `explode()` to make array. Change the line to `$m_selected = isset( $_POST[ 'multiselect' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'multiselect' ] : array_map('trim',explode(",",$row['mselect']));`

Comment: It works. It's funny because I've been trying to use explode function before but maybe I didn't fully refreshed the form to see the effect. Thank you. I will change those $_POST to this->input->post :)

Comment: I put this as my suggested answer, including the last edit to trim spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP `explode()` to make an array of the database data "small, large":

Change the line in your view to:

```
$m_selected = isset( $_POST[ 'multiselect' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'multiselect' ] : array_map('trim',explode(",",$row['mselect']));
```

The explode function makes an array of the values similar to

```
array('small', 'large');
```

And the `array_map('trim',$array)` function removes any spaces in the data